# MongoDB best backup Practices

Tags: backup, mongodb

I have the following questions to ask:

1. What are the best practices for MongoDB backup
2. Is mongodump a good option for data greater than 50GB?
3. Does mongodump have any adverse effect on mongodb while it is backing up?
4. Is it possible to have incremental backup using mongodump?
5. How fast is mongodump in backing up a data of size of 50-100 GB?
6. If at all one uses mongodump to take backup how often should it be performed (Considering the load we'll be adding on DB)?

I understand some of the questions might be very trivial but I'm having a lot of confusion choosing solution for backing up my production database which is currently 60GB large.

Thank you!

Comment: A lot of these are going to depend on your specific use case (which we don't know anything about). You should read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/), do performance testing, and figure out your [RTO/RPO](https://www.mongodb.com/backup-and-its-role-disaster-recovery) before deciding on a backup strategy.